# Adjust memory size not success for LaTeX by TexLive in Windows 11

Tags: tabularray, memory

I make a LaTeX file with a long table with `tabularray.sty` and `xelatex` and Texworks show me that memory size not enough. My computer has 16GB memory and I allocated 50GB virtual memory for my computer.
[image]
[image]
And I set **texmf.cnf** file as:

```
TEXLIVE_WINDOWS_TRY_EXTERNAL_PERL = 0
main_memory=70000000
extra_mem_bot=70000000
font_mem_size=70000000
pool_size=70000000
buf_size=70000000
```

The error in LaTeX is:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=78000000]. \end
```

So, this table need the memory size that bigger than 78000000?

It is terrible, am I wrong?

Comment: Often `TeX capacity exceeded` is caused by some recursive macro call. `longtblr` has other restrictions on its size which probably will be hit way before TeX's memory is exceeded.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum Yes, you are right. I should use `longtable`

Comment: note that xetex does not use dynamic memory allocation the tex memory limits are fixed size arrays of sizes specifed (usually) in `texmf.cnf` the physical and virtual memory limits of the operating system that you show in the screenshot are not relevant, on modern machines they will be much larger than the tex limits. your system memory is being reported in mega bytes, the tex memory is being reported in array sizes, so units of  8bytes